# How to resolve (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.DefaultSource) in pyspark i'm using pycharm

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

With Pycharm I'm getting this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.DefaultSource`
How can I resolve this issue?

**I tried:**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "/Users/diwakarkumar/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/").appName(
    "my_job").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

**I also tried setting the classpath of the jars also .bash_profile:**

```
export CLASSPATH=~/my_jars/
```

I had many jars in `my_jars` but still didn't get it to work. I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide comma separated jarfiles instead of directory path in spark.jars

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "/Users/diwakarkumar/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/jar1,/Users/diwakarkumar/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/jar2").appName(
    "my_job").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Alternatively you can also use package option.